# Печать графика в jfreechart на нескольких страницах

Tags: java

Есть построенный чертеж в jfreechart, как его распечатать в абсолютных размерах? 
поясню, есть какой то рисунок размером 6800 мм на 4500 мм. Мне нужно распечатать его не на одном листе (как это делает по умолчанию jfreechart), а на нескольких с сохранением размера, т.е. на нескольких A4, которые я в дальнейшем склею.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел как это сделать.
Может кому пригодиться:

```
public class PrintManager implements java.awt.print.Printable {
// константы для печати альбомной ориентации
public static final double maxXInPage = 19.2;
public static final double maxYInPage = 28.2;
// лучше сместить график, из-за рамки не видно саму линию
public static final double startIndex = -1.;
public void realPrint(XYDataset dataset){
        this.dataset = dataset;
        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        printJob.setPrintable(this);
        if (printJob.printDialog())
            try {
                printJob.print();
            } catch (PrinterException pe) {
                System.out.println("Error printing: " + pe);
            }
    }

public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int number) 
                                                        throws PrinterException {     
              // создаем чарт в зависимости от номера печатаемой страницы
              JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset, number);
              if (chart == null){
                   return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
              }
              ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
              panel.print(graphics, pageFormat, 0);

              return(PAGE_EXISTS);
       }

private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset, int number) {

    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            "",      
            "",      
            "",      
            dataset, 
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            false,   
            false,   
            false    
    );
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    plot.setAxisOffset(new RectangleInsets(UnitType.ABSOLUTE, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0));

    final XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
    renderer.setBaseLinesVisible(true);
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0, false);
    plot.setRenderer(renderer);
    double maxX = ((XYSeriesCollection) dataset).getSeries(0).getMaxX();
    double maxY = ((XYSeriesCollection) dataset).getSeries(0).getMaxY();
    double xStart = startIndex;
    double yStart = startIndex;
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
        if (xStart + maxXInPage < maxX){
            xStart += maxXInPage;
        } else {
            xStart = startIndex;
            if (yStart + maxYInPage < maxY){
                yStart += maxYInPage;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    double xFinish = xStart + maxXInPage;
    double yFinish = yStart + maxYInPage;

    ValueAxis xAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
    xAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
    Range rangeX = new Range(xStart, xFinish);
    xAxis.setDefaultAutoRange(rangeX);
    xAxis.setRange(rangeX);
    xAxis.setVisible(false);
    ValueAxis yAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();
    yAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
    Range rangeY = new Range(yStart, yFinish);
    yAxis.setDefaultAutoRange(rangeY);
    yAxis.setRange(rangeY);
    yAxis.setVisible(false);
    return chart;
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Может поможет - [How to call print option of JFreeChart chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673872/how-to-call-print-option-of-jfreec).

Comment: немного не то, это вызов печати из другого места программы, а не из контекстное меню

Comment: А разница?

Comment: Мне нужно распечатать в реальных размерах, а этот способ просто вызывает сам факт печати